# App freezes while reading data from a file and plotting the graph in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-graphview

I am using Windows 7, 64bit and Android Studio.

I am doing two tasks-

1. Reading data from file in AsyncTaskRunner in doInBackground. Then I am publishing the progress and passing the data.
2. In progress update, I am reading the data and plotting it to the graph.

I am using GraphView to plot the graph.

Problem- My app freezes after couple of seconds and "Application is not responding" displays.

I am new to android programming, so please guide me.

Here is the code-

```
package com.example.user.ui_layout;

//import java.util.Random;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    private int lastX = 0;

    String line;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GraphView graphView = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        GridLabelRenderer gridLabelRenderer = graphView.getGridLabelRenderer();

        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        series.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphView.addSeries(series);

        Viewport viewport = graphView.getViewport();
        viewport.setScrollable(false);
        viewport.setScalable(true);

        viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        viewport.setMinY(-50);
        viewport.setMaxY(300);

        viewport.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        viewport.setMinX(0);
        viewport.setMaxX(200);


        new AsyncTaskRunner().execute("");
    }


    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard, "demo.txt");
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        publishProgress(y);


                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return line;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... s)
        {

            series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, s[0]), true, 1800);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Insted of publish progress, put the data in some array and in onPostExecute append the whole data.

Comment: @NigamPatro I want the graph to be in real-time. I want to use this application for UDP communication. So, I thought I will try a simpler task (reading from file) and then go to UDP. So, I can't append whole data in onPostExecute as the plotting of graph has to be in real-time.

Comment: Then make it something like, update 5 or 10 data and append it

Comment: @NigamPatro Update 5 or 10 data and append it before publishing the progress ? Ok. I will try it out now and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: I am not dure how can I pass array to ProgressUpdate. Also, in the appenddata ( graphVIew), I can plot only one data at a time. So, I dont think updating 5 or 10 data and appending will work.

Comment: Modify the second parameter of AsyncTask to List so that you can pass a list of data. If there is no method to append a list of data then add them using a loop.

Comment: Why do you need Thread.sleep(3000), That might be the cause of being freeze

Comment: I understood that, my problem is how do I pass that array through publishprogress ? publishProgress(????); I cant pass it as publishProgress(array[]); or publishProgress(array);

Comment: @Kingcesc I am using it only during initialization. It will be executed only once, that is during the startion of app. After I open the app, I want to plot graph after 2-3 sec instead of plotting the graph as soon as the app opens. I removed the thread.slepp, but problem is still occuring.